# Changing the label color of radio button onclick in this custom css

Tags: css, onclick, radio-button

I have attached plunker link in this.

Can anyone please tell me how can i edit this so that i can change the label color onclick of radio button .

https://plnkr.co/edit/oajIUWAv2cQy3BrFhlhB?p=preview

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritema" name="ritem" value="ropt1">
    <label for="ritema">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritemb" name="ritem" value="ropt2">
    <label for="ritemb">Option 2</label>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.radio-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-item input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-item label {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.radio-item label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I included two solutions below:

1. First:  `:active` colors the label while it is clicked.
2. Second:  `:checked` colors the label while the checkbox is checked.

```css
/* CHANGE LABEL COLOR WHILE CLICKED */
.radio-item input[type=radio]:active + label {
  color: red;
}

/* CHANGE LABEL COLOR WHILE CHECKED

.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}

*/

.radio-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-item input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-item label {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.radio-item label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritema" name="ritem" value="ropt1">
    <label for="ritema">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritemb" name="ritem" value="ropt2">
    <label for="ritemb">Option 2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `input[type=radio]:checked + label` this selector to select the label that is immediately after the selected checkbox.

check the code below

```css
.radio-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-item input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-item label {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.radio-item label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
.radio-item input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritema" name="ritem" value="ropt1">
    <label for="ritema">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="ritemb" name="ritem" value="ropt2">
    <label for="ritemb">Option 2</label>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added classes to the input tags class=ropt1 and class=ropt2

Label highlights based on radio checked or unchecked

```css
input[type='radio'].ropt1,input[type='radio'].ropt2{
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].ropt1:checked + label {
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
input[type="radio"].ropt2:checked + label {
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  
  <div class="radio-item">
      <input type="radio" id="ritema" name="ritem" value="ropt1" class="ropt1">
      <label for="ritema">Option 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio-item">
      <input type="radio" id="ritemb" name="ritem" value="ropt2" class="ropt2">
      <label for="ritemb">Option 2</label>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```